# CSS File changes keep getting reset when creating a new branch in Git/VS Code

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code

This is a very strange problem that I'm not even sure how to search for.

When I create a new branch through VS Code for my application (a Node JS app), there's nothing unusual that happens. I can run the app, but once I run it, a single CSS file resets itself to lose a bunch of critical changes that were committed long ago.

I've cleared my Chrome cache to no avail. It's odd that the reversion of changes only occurs when running the app. I can "discard" the changes and the app runs fine.

Why would this be happening? This is a cross-platform problem (I run Linux, the dev team runs Windows/MacOS).

Comment: the file on disk is OK, but the version you see in the browser is wrong? See on the Network tab where the CSS is loaded from. And reload with Shift-Ctrl-R

Comment: could that css file be written to disk by the nodejs app itself ? set the access rights on that file to "read-only", and see if some error appears when running your app.

Comment: The CSS file on the disk gets changed. I'm thinking it _could_ be a caching issue with VS code, but it's hard to say. The CSS file is only served by the node app (simple Express app), so unlikely to be written to.